# how to open "styles", "computed", "layout" , "event liesteners" when using sources dev tool of chrome dev tool?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I am newbie with css and here is my problem.

When I using elements, I can the styles, computed, layout, event listeners, DOM breakpoints as you can see in this picture [image about styles, computed, layout when click to elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3ZVd.png)

But when I click to Sources, it does not show styles, computed, layout, event listeners, DOM breakpoints as I want, you can see in this picture [image when click to sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2F6t.png)

I want to show styles, computed, layout, event listeners when I click to sources, it help me so much when I code, and I can debug and see where is the bug. Could you please tell me how to show these ? Thank you vey much.

Comment: The Sources tab shows all the files that are loaded from the server. Scripts, images, stylesheets and so on. Those don't have styles or event listeners. They are *files*. Only *elements* have styles and event listeners, which is why you're seeing them in the elements tab. What exactly are you asking here? Why do you want to see the sources and a random element's styles at the same time during debugging? Can you clarify?

Comment: @ChrisG thank you for your comment, here is the picture I take from the lesson I studied, as you can see, he use Sources and chrome still show styles, computed, layout. Here is the picture https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipPVPmsJ2a9zyTAjJL-aGlo9VlfE5KVwL1kvNpqg

Comment: You can right-click the Elements tab and click "move to bottom" to display both the elements and the sources tab.